# Fill angular input using javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Setting element's `value` is not working. It does not act like user typing. When I submit this input, popup tells me that I didn't fill input at all. How can I fill this input element just like users do?

```
<div class="login-input input-group" data-ng-class="{'invalid' : !valid}">
<input id="alias-input" type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched" tabindex="1" data-ng-model="formData.alias" data-ng-keydown="sendAlias($event)" maxlength="10" data-gemius-event="click" data-gemius-parameters="['place=login','inputbox=login','met=onclick']"
    spellcheck="false">
</div>
```

I tried:

`angular.element(document.querySelector("#alias-input")).val("foo");`

`document.getElementById('alias-input').value = 'foo';`

Comment: I am not developer of this site. I want to create automatic test and I have problems with filling this input.

Comment: What are you using to add the test? any framework?

Comment: @xyz I am using Watin.

Comment: @Chellappan this is angularjs he is talking about. So the link to this documentation is not relevant, it is the wrong framework.

Comment: @Dafie your problem is data-ng-model overrides any change you make to the value during digest cycles. So you need to set the value after any digest cycle ends or if you can guarantee somehow the last digest cycle has occurred, change the value then.

Comment: @dafie: does Watin has methods to similulate how a user types, something like: `sendKeys()`? SO you grab the element by `css` and send keys to it?

Comment: @xyz it does, but its not working. Input has text, but when I click submit I got popup saying that input is empty.

Answer (score 13):

This is what worked for me:

```js
const event = new Event('input', { bubbles: true }); 
document.querySelectorAll('[formcontrolname = "idNumber"]')[0].value = '123456789';
document.querySelectorAll('[formcontrolname = "idNumber"]')[0].dispatchEvent(event);
```

This was tested on a page with Ionic 3.9.2 and Angular 5.0.3

Comment: Thank you, this helped me with a similar issue. Setting the value without calling dispatchEvent didn't allow to save the form.

Comment: @Asdrubal - This helped me too! Thank you so much!  Why do I need to create a new Event() though. And dispatch it. What exactly does this do under the hood?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can set an ng-model attribute for the input element in the html like: ng-model = "inputValue". In the controller of this view, after inject the $scope, now you can set $scope.inputValue = "foo" and it will automatic update the input value.

Hope it helps.