# Java Script automatic authentification fills in the credentials but it says incomplete

Tags: javascript, html, authentication

I would like to automatically login to this example website: https://portal.videc.info/.
I'm quiet new to Java Script and can't figure the issue.
I'm using the following code to write the values of username and password (not the correct ones):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value=('userid')
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value=('password')
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[3].click()
```

The values are shown in the input boxes. After the button gets pressed it says error 11 "credentials incomplete". When I manually (via keyboard input) remove the last character ('d') of the username and the password and add it again it's working and I get the error 12 (invalid credentials).
I assume that I can't write the values that way. The Website doesn't recognize any input by using the code. Does somebody knows how I can make this work?

Comment: Out of testing, it's good enough for security, so there will not be any bot can bruteforce inserting every possible username and password. Cheers!

Comment: I think that website was built with Angular. I also don't know whether Angular literally disallow that kind of "input from console" behavior or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution in this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53628112/fill-angular-input-using-javascript):

```
const event = new Event('input', { bubbles: true }); 
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value=('userid')
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].dispatchEvent(event)
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value=('password')
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].dispatchEvent(event)
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[3].click()
```

Thanks @Dhana D. for the hint with Angular!